# powershell command wmiobject not giving output

Tags: sql, powershell

i am running a powershell command through SQL,please find below code

```
     declare @sql varchar(200)

set @sql = 'powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage| select FriendlyName'


EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

its gives me output

```
 output
'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NULL
```

why it is giving like that if i remove select than powershell command is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the arguments in quotes like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(200)
set @sql = 'powershell.exe "Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage| select FriendlyName"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Just now it's basically running two separate commands which are:

```
powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage|
```

Then

```
select| FriendlyName
```

So the second command is invalid and causing the error, the quotes group them together to make it process it as one.

Comment: but what about SQL

Comment: @deepti I've updated my answer so its set in the variable for you